# Deploying Dataflow job that runs for X hours

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We are deploying/triggering Dataflow streaming jobs through Airflow using flex template. We want these streaming jobs to run, say for 24 hours (or until a certain clock time), then stop/cancel on its own. Is there a parameter in Dataflow (pipeline setting like max workers) that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no parameter and automatic approach to stop or drain a `Dataflow` job.

You can do that with an `Airflow` dag.
Example you can create a `cron` dag with `Airflow` (every 24 hours) having the responsability to stop or drain the `Dataflow` job, there is a built in [operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html) to do that :

```py
stop_dataflow_job = DataflowStopJobOperator(
    task_id="stop-dataflow-job",
    location="europe-west3",
    job_name_prefix="start-template-job",
)
```

> To stop one or more Dataflow pipelines you can use
> DataflowStopJobOperator. Streaming pipelines are drained by default,
> setting drain_pipeline to False will cancel them instead. Provide
> job_id to stop a specific job, or job_name_prefix to stop all jobs
> with provided name prefix.